# How do I open ctrlp plugin file suggestions in Insert mode?

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

I'm using [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin to switch to other files in Vim by pressing `Ctrl-p`. But this only works in normal mode. I want to trigger it by pressing the same set of keys in insert mode as well. How can I do that? I couldn't find any mapping for insert mode in the help doc.

Comment: Can't you remap it yourself with `inoremap <C-p> <Esc>:CtrlP<CR>`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the mapping by yourself: Ctrlp provides an ex command to trigger the fuzzy finding: `:CtrlP` so you can create an insert mode mapping which will switch to command mode and trigger the command:

```
inoremap <C-p> <Esc>:CtrlP<CR>`
```

Note that as `<C-p>` is used to navigate the pop up menu, this mapping could create a unwanted behavior (I'm not sure I didn't test it) but in this case you should be able to use `pumvisible()` in an expression mapping to check if the menu is visible and trigger the built-in `<C-p>` or the `CtrlP` ex command.